# Typescript - "Cannot find name" errors in React components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am migrating my existing React code over to TypeScript and I am hitting a lot of issues, one of them being a lot of "Cannot find name" errors when I make my `.js` files `.ts` files.

Here is the code in question:

```
import React from 'react';

const Footer = ({ children, inModal }) => (
    <footer className={'tableBottomPanel' + (inModal ? " in-modal" : "") }>
        <div>
            {children}
        </div>
    </footer>
);

export default Footer;
```

The five lines from `<footer>` to `</footer>` are underlined in red and give me various errors, depending where I hover my mouse, such as:

- Cannot find name 'footer'.
- '>' expected
- Cannot find name 'div'
- Unterminated regular expression literal
- Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'RegExp'

Here is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/", // path to output directory
        "sourceMap": true, // allow sourcemap support
        "strictNullChecks": true, // enable strict null checks as a best practice
        "module": "es6", // specify module code generation
        "jsx": "react", // use typescript to transpile jsx to js
        "target": "es5", // specify ECMAScript target version
        "allowJs": true, // allow a partial TypeScript and JavaScript codebase
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom"
        ],
        "types": [
            "node"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/"
    ]
}
```

I am incredibly confused and would greatly appreciate some help!

Comment: Have you added the typings for React/React DOM? Also, maybe it should be named .tsx.

Comment: Is this code in a `. tsx` OR `. ts` file? To use `jsx`the extension must be `tsx`

Comment: Although it seems like the error gets solved for everyone by renaming `ts` -> `tsx` but not mine, because my file is already `.tsx` and it had happened multiple times but gets solved by itself.

Comment: @CircuitPlanet I am facing this issue,getting error in tsx files. Know how to fix it ?

Answer (score 364, accepted):

Typescript isn't expecting to see JSX in your Typescript file. The easiest way to resolve this is to rename your file from `.ts` to `.tsx`.

[JSX in Typescript Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This worked for me. All my previous JSX files were using `.js` extension so I just figured changing it to `.ts` would be okay. Even though this works for me, I'm curious as to if you know of another way to resolve this especially because changing everything to `.tsx` would require renaming all of my module imports.

Comment: This can also occur when a file is mistakenly named `.ts` instead of `.tsx`

Comment: @Lunster That's exactly what the question is about.

Comment: @coreyward No, not exactly, but analogous yes. The original question was about jsx and tsx, whereas I found this page on Google with the same error, but the cause was ts instead of tsx files. Your answer would not be a solution to my problem unless reformulated to be more general.

Comment: @Lunster Original question: “I'm hitting a lot of issues…when I make my .js files .ts files.”.

Comment: @coreyward 

If you think JSX and TS are exactly the same, your definition of "exact" is questionable. Your answer serves those searching for this error message. In my scenario, the initial answer "TypeScript isn't expecting to see JSX" doesn't apply to me.
 
Some like myself will be working only with TSX; not JSX, and will Google errors that match the question subject, scroll down to the answer and assume that your answer doesn't apply, because I was never working with JSX as your answer implies, rather; TS.  

There are other ways to reach this error that your answer precludes.

Comment: @Lunster The OP switched his codebase to Typescript and renamed his files from `.js` to `.ts`. So he had `.ts` files that contain JSX, and therefore needed to be `.tsx`. TSX is not a language, it's just an extension. If you needed to use a `.tsx` extension for your Typescript file then you are using JSX. [Here's the manual](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html)

Comment: My comment is intended to help people like myself, who reached this page as a result of a situation where the mistake is simply missing an `x` from `tsx` extension, but the error leads to this page. You are not incorrect but your answer is for one situation of many that can lead people here.

You are correct about the differences between extensions and languages but that is not in dispute, and your answer, while correct, doesn't cater for all contexts for why people arrive here, which my comment intended to help with. It adds clarity to an answer I upvoted for being helpful. Context matters.

Comment: @Lunster I still don't see the difference between having to rename `.ts` files to `.tsx` files and “simply missing an `x` from `tsx` extension”. Are these not the same thing?

Comment: `"js" to "ts"`, which is how the question is formulated, is not exactly the same as `ts` to `tsx` but share the same essence, albeit an inexact one, and it seems we are resolving this ambiguity differently because of context, my comment will help those who reached this page as a result of making a simple typo, without needing to parse all the ambiguities involved in your terse answer and a question that doesn't quite match my scenario, but still proved helpful in solving the problem.

Comment: @Lunster He migrated to Typescript, so the files were named `.ts`, and the solution was to rename to `tsx`. I can add some additional language to make it clear that the rename is from `.ts` to `.tsx`, but I honestly don't think it's unclear.

Comment: There's no need, your answer is correct if the problem is exactly the same as the OPs, but mine was not.  Yet the `title` of this question *does* apply to me, leading me here from Google: `Typescript - “Cannot find name” errors in React components`, which covers a lot more scenarios than your answer provides.

Like I said, you are not incorrect, but people are arriving here for problems that differ to the OP's, and so will be mentally parsing otherwise understandably terse answers under the ambiguous title, differently. My comment clarifies ambiguities for my situation.

Comment: you need to import react also if you forgot

Answer (score 12):

If you have ".tsx" file and still getting error then, you should add/modify value for **"jsx"** from **"preserve"** --> **"react-jsx"** as below in tsconfig.json.

Now, you must **stop** and **restart the server** again.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx", // change here
    ...
    ...

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution for me.

Comment: I did the same, but still it's not working for me.

Answer (score 7):

This issue can also arise if, having created .tsx files, you don't include them in the tsconfig file:

```
"include": [
  "wwwroot/js/**/*.ts",
  "wwwroot/js/**/*.tsx" // <-- this needed to be added in my case
],
```

Answer (score 2):

Another subtle way this can happen is if you `tsconfig.json` doesn't "include" the file that's giving the editor warning.

**You still have to get the other configs correct,** and they vary depending on bundler and TypeScript version. See https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/typescript#typescript-configuration for advice, most of which is covered in posts above this.

**But before you mess with those settings** make sure the `tsconfig.json` at project root is telling VSCode that your file is to be treated as TypeScript. This example assumes your source files are under `./src`

```
// tsconfig.json excerpt
{

  // COMMON PROBLEM 1: this include ignores .tsx files
  // "include": ["./src/**/*.ts"],

  // COMMON PROBLEM 2: this include ignores subdirectories
  // "include": ["./src/*.ts?"],

  // THIS IS PROBABLY CLOSE TO WHAT YOU WANT
  "include": ["./src/**/*.ts?"],
....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error in a file with no extension. It was simply `filename` without extensions so VSCode assumed it to be TS. When I renamed my file to `filename.js` the error went away.

Though, If you want the file to be in typescript and don't want the error, the accepted answer (`filename.tsx`) is the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case others come across this. I use StencilJS, which uses react-like tsx files, without react. My issue was that I loaded the SRC directory in vscode. The correction is loading the parent of the SRC directory, which has the appropriate config.ts, tsconfig.json, etc. This allowed it to recognize tsx files correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a .tsx file but my error didn't gone.
when I removed 
`import React from "react";`
from top of my next.js, the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

The errors you are seeing when migrating your existing React code to TypeScript are occurring because TypeScript is a strongly typed language, and requires that all variables and objects be defined with a specific type.

In your code, you are using JSX syntax to define your footer component, but you have not explicitly defined the types for the props that are being passed in. TypeScript is not able to infer the types of these props from the JSX syntax alone, which is why you are seeing the "Cannot find name" errors.

To fix these errors, you can update your code as follows:

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';

interface Props {
  children: ReactNode;
  inModal: boolean;
}

const Footer: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, inModal }) => (
  <footer className={`tableBottomPanel ${inModal ? "in-modal" : ""}`}>
    <div>{children}</div>
  </footer>
);

export default Footer;
```

Answer (score 0):

I already had .tsx files in src in a create-react-app project and I could see the project was running fine.

Simply turning VSCode off and on again solved this for me.

Answer (score 0):

if this happens to you and are using vite as your bundler. Make sure both tsconfig.json and tsconfig.node.json file have  `"jsx": "react-jsx",` in the compilerOptions.