# React Native BottomTabNavigator navigation not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I created a BottomTabNavigator app with expose, it's my first project with react-native. On the last tab I have a FlatList with a few elements which should open different Views outside the TabNavigation. But when I click on a item in the ListView, I get the following error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.navigation.navigate'. This also happens when I try to do it with props, but props also won't work properly in my project.

I'm trying to fix this for two days and I don't know any further. Can anyone please help me with this? In addition, has someone a good guide for navigation and props?

**App.tsx**

```
export default function App() {
  const isLoadingComplete = useCachedResources();
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  if (!isLoadingComplete) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return (
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <Navigation colorScheme={colorScheme} />
        <StatusBar />
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

**index.tsx**

```
export default function Navigation({ colorScheme }: { colorScheme: ColorSchemeName }) {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      linking={LinkingConfiguration}
      theme={colorScheme === 'dark' ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
      <RootNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

function RootNavigator() {

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={BottomTabNavigator} />
      <Stack.Screen name="WebViewImprint" component={WebViewImprint} />
      <Stack.Screen name="MenuFlatList" component={MenuFlatList} />

      <Stack.Screen name="NotFound" component={NotFoundScreen} options={{ title: 'Oops!' }} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

**BottomTabNavigator.tsx**

```
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator<BottomTabParamList>();

export default function BottomTabNavigator() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  return (
      { .... }
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="TabMenu"
        component={TabMenuNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: "Menü",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <TabBarIcon name="ios-code" color={color} />,
        }}
      />
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
}

function TabBarIcon(props: { name: string; color: string }) {
  return <Ionicons size={30} style={{ marginBottom: -3 }} {...props} />;
}

const TabMenuStack = createStackNavigator<TabMenuParamList>();

function TabMenuNavigator() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <TabMenuStack.Navigator>
      <TabMenuStack.Screen
        name="TabMenu"
        component={TabMenu}
        options={{ 
          header: props => <StacknavigatorImage />,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: Colors[colorScheme].barBackgroundColor
          }
        }}
      />
    </TabMenuStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

**MenuFlatListComponent.tsx**

```
const Item = ({ title } : {title: any}) => (
     <View style={styles.item}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
     </View>
);

export default class MenuFlatList extends React.Component {

     render(){

          return (
               <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                    <FlatList style={styles.flatList}
                    data={DATA}
                    renderItem={({item} : {item: any}) => {
                         return (
                              <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
                                   item.navigation.navigate('WebViewImprint');
                              }}>
                                   <View style={styles.item}>
                                             <Image source={item.icon} style={styles.icon} />
                                             <Item title={item.title} />
                                   </View>
                              </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                         );}
                         
                    }
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                    />
               </SafeAreaView>
          );
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access navigation which is passed to the MenuFlatList component as a prop you should do like below

```
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
         this.props.navigation.navigate('WebViewImprint');
   }}>
```

Any screen component in the navigation will receive a 'navigation' props which you can use to navigate to other screens.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for yours response. I tried this before, but the following error appears: Property 'navigation' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.ts(2339). Any idea why this happens?

Comment: change to export default class MenuFlatList extends extends React.Component<Props> {

Comment: I added <Props>, but the following error appears: Cannot find name 'Props'.ts(2304).

Comment: can you check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51158080/typescript-cannot-find-name-errors-in-react-components

Comment: I did, all the files have .tsx endings.

Comment: Seems like there is something wrong with your typescript config, there are multiple answers on the issue, you might have to tryout and fix it, as for navigation as long as you have the prop you can navigate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221493/discussion-between-mapof-and-guruparan-giritharan).